# Rails how to get entries where we ignore deleted_at property along with other properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the model `Store`. I would like to check an existence of an entry in the database by `Store.where(:google_place_id => 'XXXX')`. I just want to check if it exists in the database, regardless of whether it's (soft) deleted or not.

When I try that, rails runs this SQL: 
`SELECT  "stores".* FROM "stores" WHERE "stores"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "stores"."google_place_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["google_place_id", "XXX"], ["LIMIT", 1]]`

After doing some research, I stumbled upon the `unscoped` property, which would remove this `deleted_at` clause from being included, but when that also gets rid of the entire WHERE clause. E.g if I tried this `Store.where(:google_place_id => 'XXXX').unscoped` it runs this SQL `SELECT  "stores".* FROM "stores" WHERE "stores"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "stores"."google_place_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["google_place_id", "XXX"], ["LIMIT", 1]]`

Can someone clarify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you using `acts_as_paranoid ` or `paranoia` Gem?

Comment: Yes I am using the `paranoia` gem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `paranoia` gem README:

```
Store.with_deleted.where(google_place_id: 'xxx')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the unscoped scope to ignore not deleted scope

```
Store.unscoped.where(:google_place_id => 'XXXX')
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can try to change it's ordering like:

```
Store.unscoped.where(:google_place_id => 'XXXX')
```